# How to change color of stacked bars after certain value in Swimmer ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm wondering how can I change the color of the stacked bar after 2 days (geometric vertical line)?

As a result, I want to get the figure marked with yellow color.

Here is an example from my data frame with the indicator (marked in yellow) if the subject continues after two days.

[image: Dataframe]
[image: Swimmer plot I require]
[image: Swimmer plot original]

```r
 ggplot(aes(subjectID, endTime)) + 
   scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue"))+ 
      geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill=factor(stage))) + 
   geom_point(data=df, aes(subjectID, endTime, colour=responseType, shape=responseType),  size=6) +
   coord_flip() +
   scale_colour_manual(values=c('#20A387FF','#2D708EFF')) + 
   scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-0.2, 20), breaks=0:20) + 
      labs(fill="Treatment status",  # Add labels
        x="Subject ID ", y="Days since hospital admission",
        title="Patient trajectories",
        caption="Hypothetical example") +
   geom_hline(yintercept=2, linetype="dashed",  size=1)+ # , col=c('DC0000B2')
   theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), # Put title in the middle of plot
         plot.caption = element_text(size=7, hjust=0))+ # Make caption size smaller
   theme_minimal()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I would do this with `geom_rect`

```r
ggplot(df, aes(subjectID, endTime)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue")) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = factor(stage))) + 
  geom_rect(aes(ymin = 2, ymax = endTime, xmin = as.numeric(subjectID) - 0.45,
                xmax = as.numeric(subjectID) + 0.45), fill = '#fff200',
            data = df[df$isContinued,]) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = responseType, shape = responseType),  size = 6) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c('#20A387FF','#2D708EFF')) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.2, 20), breaks = 0:20) + 
  labs(fill    = "Treatment status",
       x       = "Subject ID ", 
       y       = "Days since hospital admission",
       title   = "Patient trajectories",
       caption ="Hypothetical example") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 2, linetype = "dashed", size = 1) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(plot.title   = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        plot.caption = element_text(size = 7, hjust = 0))
```

[image]

---

**Data in reproducible format**

```r
df <- data.frame(subjectID = factor(1:10, 10:1),
                 stage = rep(c("treated", "untreated"), times = c(6, 4)),
                 startTime = 0,
                 endTime = c(8, 12, 1.7, 1.8, 15,17, 8, 14, 1, 1.5),
                 isContinued = rep(c(!0, !1, !0, !1), times = c(2, 2, 4, 2)),
                 responseType = rep(c("death", "discharge"), 5))

df
#>    subjectID     stage startTime endTime isContinued responseType
#> 1          1   treated         0     8.0        TRUE        death
#> 2          2   treated         0    12.0        TRUE    discharge
#> 3          3   treated         0     1.7       FALSE        death
#> 4          4   treated         0     1.8       FALSE    discharge
#> 5          5   treated         0    15.0        TRUE        death
#> 6          6   treated         0    17.0        TRUE    discharge
#> 7          7 untreated         0     8.0        TRUE        death
#> 8          8 untreated         0    14.0        TRUE    discharge
#> 9          9 untreated         0     1.0       FALSE        death
#> 10        10 untreated         0     1.5       FALSE    discharge
```